# Running Tensorflow with java on windows

Tags: java, tensorflow

Hello I'm trying to setup tensorflow with java on my windows 10 machine.

Here are the steps that I've done yet:

I've used a maven project and I have put the dependencies in my pom.
I've downloaded the jni dll for windows that I've put in my path
When I run the HelloTF example that is provided I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\cth\AppData\Local\Temp\tensorflow_native_libraries-1522143642219-0\tensorflow_jni.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:101)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:70)
    at org.tensorflow.Graph.<clinit>(Graph.java:258)
    at machinelearning.HelloTF.main(HelloTF.java:13)
```

The dll is available in the PATH variable of my environment but it don't seems to load it (I've checked with debug). As the code does not seems to load the dll it extract the dll in C:\Users\cth\AppData\Local\Temp\tensorflow_native_libraries-1522143642219-0\tensorflow_jni.dll and then tries to load it but once again the load fail and the program ends up with this error.

Any idea of what I could try to solve this DLL load fail ?

Comment: Did you check system requirement is satisfied or not in your environment it was pasted in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

Comment: You may also want to look at [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14456) about msvcp40.dll

Comment: Thanks @DinushaDilanka, I've rechecked yesterday that my environment was filling all requirements and even if it is it seems that I'm still not able to load the library. I've also installed the library via pip and I've attempted to load the library with python and it fails too.

Comment: Thank you @as, when I've read the issue I was happy to have a new clue to this problem but I have the msvcp40.dll already on my computer so it seems not related to this issue.

Comment: @ChristopheThiry, You mean even python also you faced same issue?

Comment: @DinushaDilanka yes it can't load the library. This is probably related to my machine where I don't have admin right or something like that but I didn't find what was wrong yet

Comment: Can you tell which tensorflow version you used?

Comment: I used 1.6.0 (no gpu) with both java and python